# traceback error when trying to generate credentials for google assistant SDK

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk, traceback

so I'm trying to use my raspberry pi as a google assistant and followed the steps on the google developers guide page. I get to the command:

`google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \  --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json`

but when I enter it into my terminal, im met with the following traceback error:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype  --save --headless --client-secrets  ~/client_secret_978034168413-0l332bgdhmjv0uhop9g7g1ocufva7k9t.apps.googleusercontent.com.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/google-oauthlib-tool", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/tool/__main__.py", line 100, in main
    scopes=scope
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 181, in from_client_secrets_file
    client_config = json.load(json_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I don't know what causes this and I have pretty much no experience with python. I tried to google the reasons and other ways to execute the command but all of them yield the same error. I am connecting to my pi using ssh from my PC but I doubt that would be the reason. please help, my project is due soon and I need to get this up and running.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like your client-secrets file is maybe not valid JSON.  Try to copy the contents into a service like https://jsonlint.com/ or read it via Python. Check that your file actually exists on the Pi (do `ls ~`), too, that's a common gotcha.

Comment: @jake2389 thanks, i redownloaded the json and it works perfectly now. this entire python trip is like a huge learning curve for me

Comment: Python is an excellent language, and usually very easy to learn, but learning anything under pressure at school will always suck. Glad you sorted it out. Cheers.